# Java Object graph validation

Tags: java, recursion

I have java object `Map<Integer, SortedMap<Integer, Pair<Integer, String>>>` data. I am passing this object to recursive method to build objects of each key in the above map. Please see the example below.

For ex,

```
<1 - <1, Pair<1, 'A'>>

<2 - <1, Pair<1, 'A'>>
     <2, Pair<2, 'B'>>
```

I want to check the circular dependency on the above map. Please see the example below.

```
<9994 - <1, Pair<9995, 'X'>>
        <2, Pair<2, 'B'>>

<9995 - <1, Pair<9994, 'Y'>>
        <2, Pair<2, 'B'>>
```

Above 9994 contains 9995 and 9995 contains 9994. This is invalid and should error out the programme.

Can anyone suggest me the best way to perform this validation?

Thanks.

private static Boolean validate(
      Map> input,
      Set object) throws Exception {
    Boolean result = true;
    for (Pair cal : input.values()) {
      if (!object.add(cal.left))
        return false;
      result = validate(get(cal.left), object);
    }
    return result;
  }

Answer (score 1):

The check for circular dependency could be implemented via [Depth-first-search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search). Fo this, either the objects to be checked would have to be changed to contain a flag (which would indicate whether they have already been visited) or some auxiliary data structure like a list or hashmap would contain the visited nodes.

Comment: Can you give example of how can i use dfs here?

Comment: `9994` and `9995` would be tagged as 'not visited'. Then, `9994` would be tagged as 'visited'. Now all children of `9994` would be visited; the only child is `9995`. `9995` would be tagged as 'visited', and its children would ben visited. `9995` would be checked, however it already has been visited; the process would stop as we there has been a cycle.

Comment: Please move the piece of code to the original question where suitable formatting is provided.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend, you use the recursive function to put the keys in a HashSet. The HashSet "add" method returns true if the insertion was successful and false otherwise. So if there was a duplicate the add method will return false. You can use that as your validation.

If you can post some initial code snippet, we can try to help with this solution.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html

Comment: Putting keys in HashSet wont work because keys in the internal SortedMapmap can have duplicate keys. For eg. below is a valid example.

<9995 - <1, Pair<9994, 'X'>>
        <2, Pair<2, 'B'>>

<9996 - <1, Pair<9994, 'Y'>>
        <2, Pair<2, 'B'>>

Answer (score 0):

You can track the visited nodes in a collection in all levels of recursion. Check before processing if the node is already visited.

Comment: Can you give example here?

Comment: Say Node had data and link to other Node, Maintain Nodes you visited in a collection. For example:  Collection<Node> visited; void process(Node node, Collection<Node> visited) { if(!visited.contains(node)) { //do some process; visited.add(node);  process(node.getChild(),visisted);}